# xskak does not show dot after the number of the step

Tags: chessboard, xskak, chessfss

I write to [xskak](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xskak) `1. Rc8+ Rxc8 2. Rxc8+ Kg7`, but it displays `1 Rc8+ Rxc8 2 Rxc8+ Kg7` (without dots). It is annoying... Does it depend on something in the preambulum of the LaTeX file (setting languages)? I have no idea...

Comment: It depends on the style (which you can change). E.g. `\mainline[style=UF]{1. e4 e5}` will give you dots. For details check the documentation.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it appears that `xskak.pdf` isn't included in or generated by TeXLive 2012, so `texdoc xskak` just opens up the README.

Comment: You can find the documentation on CTAN. Texlive doesn't include it as it counts as non-free that the source of documentation is not included in the package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Please write up an answer to this question.

Comment: Same question. No answer since 2014...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the style (which you can change). E.g. `\mainline[style=UF]{1. e4 e5}` will give you dots. For details check the documentation.

Comment: How do i get a style like `styleC` but with a dot after of *number of move* (like `UF` but each move in a different line)?

Comment: @cis I find questions in comments not polite, they ping only one person and so are actually a request for personal support. I often ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i get a style like styleC but with a dot after of number of move (like UF but each move in a different line)? –
> skpblack
> Aug 2, 2014 at 20:43

I looked into the file `xskak.sty` and copied the stuff I need (if this goes easier, please show me):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
% xskak.sty  ============================
\xskaknewstyleitem[% copy from styleC
 opencommands={\begin{tabbing}%   --  "   --
    \hspace{.2\linewidth}\=\hspace{.2\linewidth}\=%   --  "   --
    \hspace{.2\linewidth}\= \kill},%   --  "   --
 closecommands={\end{tabbing}},%   --  "   --
 blackopen=\>\ldots,%   --  "   --
 beforenumber=\>,%   --  "   --
 beforewhite=\>,%   --  "   --
 beforeblack=\>,%   --  "   --
 afterblack=\\,%   --  "   --
 whiteopen={.\,},% copy from style UF
]{MixOfstyleUFandstyleC}

\xskaknewstyle[
styleitem=MixOfstyleUFandstyleC, 
font=\bfseries,% optional
]{styleCx}
% ====================================

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=MyGame] 
\hidemoves{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3  a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}
%\printchessgame[id=MyGame, style=styleCx]

\begin{tcbitemize}[sharp corners, raster equal height=rows,
colback=white, 
raster column skip=0mm,
boxrule=0.9pt, boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, 
]
\tcbitem[] \chessboard[]
\tcbitem[] \printchessgame[id=MyGame, style=styleCx]
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```